# Problem creating routes that point to dynamically loaded class from assemblies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working in aspnet-core 3.1 and I have this problem; I'm creating an application, it uses dll which are loaded in the configure as you can see in the follow block:

```
//src is a Dictionary based in Assemblies dynamically loaded from dll-files.

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

 foreach (var src in srcs)
 {
  routes.MapRoute( 
   name : src.ControllerAlias , 
   template : src.URL , 
   defaults : new 
      { controller = src.ControllerName , action = src.Action } ,
   constraints: null,
   dataTokens : new 
   RouteValueDictionary()
    {  { "Namespaces", new string[] { src.NameSpace} } } 
    );
 } 

}
```

The class-controllers are located in the same namespace in different dlls. But it is not a problem because I'm able to instance all class-controllers (all inheritance from Controller)

When I load the DLLs I check the 3rd-mvc-controllers and the application is able to instance the classes.

The problem is that URLs/Endpoints/Routes always return 404. (No Page)

```
class DLLModel 
{
  Assembly assmbly = null ,
  string URL = "/WebServices/Home/Index.html";
  string Controller = "HomeController"; // This is a classic Controller Example.
  string Action = "Index";
  string ControllerAlias = "HomeController.Index";
  string NameSpace = "Sample.Package";
}

//...
  var srcs = new Dictionary<string,DLLModel>();
```

Comment: Where does 'srcs' come from? What values do the shown `src` properties contain?

Comment: This is a generic example, the real class is more complex however the main ideas is that I save the dictionary of the Controllers; HomeController is the classic example that the visual studio creates.